# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `user_id`) on Heroku Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an app that works like a simplistic version of Stackoverflow (ask, answer, vote). It works perfectly fine on my computer but when I deploy it on Heroku I get this error in the Heroku logs:

ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `user_id`).

On Heroku itself the app tells me "Something went wrong, please check the logs"

My Problem is that the user_id indeed exists in my table. So I don't really know why it doesn't know this attribute. I can also log in and create users without a problem. But when I wat to create a new question I get this error....

Here the question controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :private_access, except: [:index, :show]

    def index
      @questions = if params[:term]
      Question.where("title iLIKE ? OR description iLIKE ?" , "%#{params[:term]}%", "%#{params[:term]}%")
      else 
      @questions = Question.all.order("updated_at DESC")
      end
    end 

    def new
      @question = Question.new
    end

     def create
      @question = Question.new(questions_params)
      @question.user = current_user
      if @question.save
        flash[:success] = "Fantastic #{@current_user.username} you posed a new question. Surely someone answers soon, stay tuned..."
        redirect_to root_path
      else
         render :new
      end
    end

     def show
        @question = Question.find(params[:id])
        @answer = Answer.new        
        @comment = Comment.new
        @vote = Vote.new
     end 

    def edit
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
      if @question.update(questions_params)
      flash[:success] = "Bravo #{@current_user.username}, you updated your question!"
      redirect_to root_path
      else
      flash[:danger] = "Ups, something went wrong. Please try again..."
      render :new
      end
    end


    def destroy
     @question = Question.find(params[:id])
      if @question.destroy
      flash[:danger] = "Ok #{@current_user.username}, question was deleted!"
      redirect_to root_path
      else 
      flash[:danger] = "Ups, something went wrong. Please try again..."
      redirect_to root_path
      end 
    end


    def voteup
      question = Question.find(params[:id])
      question.votes.create(user: current_user)

      flash[:success] = "Thanks #{current_user.username} for voting!"
      redirect_to question_path
    end 


    def votedown
      question = Question.find(params[:id])
      question.votes.where(user: current_user).take.try(:destroy)

      flash[:danger] = "Vote deleted!"
      redirect_to question_path

    end 



    private
        def questions_params
            params.require(:question).permit(:title, :description, :answer_id, :user_id, :body, :votes, :term)
        end 

end
```

and here my schema:

```
   create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "body"
    t.bigint "question_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["question_id"], name: "index_answers_on_question_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_answers_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "commentable_type"
    t.integer "commentable_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_questions_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", limit: 100
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "name", limit: 100
    t.string "username", limit: 50
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "voteable_id"
    t.string "voteable_type"
    t.string "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "answers", "questions"
end
```

my model associations should be fine:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_password validations: false 

has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy



validates :email, uniqueness: true, format: /@/
validates :password, presence: true, on: :create
validates :password, length: {in: 6..20 }, allow_nil: true
validates :name, presence: true
validates :username, presence: true
```

end

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
validates :title, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true, length: {minimum:10, maximum:10000}

belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :votes, as: :voteable, dependent: :destroy
```

what I tried so far:

- restart Heroku
- reload schema (db:schema:load)
- cried

Any help is highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance

EDIT: I tried resetting the database, deleted the app and migrated again....It seems like Heroku is not adding any user_id to questions, or am I wrong? it gives me the following

```
CREATE TABLE "questions" ("id" bigserial primary key, "title" character varying, "description" text, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
   -> 0.0137s
== 20180620183722 CreateQuestions: migrated (0.0138s) =========================

D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.545105 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Create (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20180620183722"]]
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.548517 #4] DEBUG -- :    (3.0ms)  COMMIT
I, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.548687 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateAnswers (20180624115634)
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.550810 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  BEGIN
== 20180624115634 CreateAnswers: migrating ====================================
-- create_table(:answers)
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.562192 #4] DEBUG -- :    (10.4ms)  CREATE TABLE "answers" ("id" bigserial primary key, "body" text, "question_id" bigint, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_3d5ed4418f"
FOREIGN KEY ("question_id")
  REFERENCES "questions" ("id")
)
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.573617 #4] DEBUG -- :    (4.7ms)  CREATE  INDEX  "index_answers_on_question_id" ON "answers"  ("question_id")
   -> 0.0228s
== 20180624115634 CreateAnswers: migrated (0.0229s) ===========================

D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.577497 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Create (2.6ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20180624115634"]]
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.580639 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.6ms)  COMMIT
I, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.580776 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateUsers (20180705164230)
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.582856 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  BEGIN
== 20180705164230 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.596461 #4] DEBUG -- :    (12.6ms)  CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" bigserial primary key, "email" character varying(100), "password_digest" character varying, "name" character varying(100), "username" character varying(50), "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
   -> 0.0135s
== 20180705164230 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0137s) =============================

D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.603402 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Create (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20180705164230"]]
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.606167 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.1ms)  COMMIT
I, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.606393 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateComments (20180708124323)
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.609250 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.4ms)  BEGIN
== 20180708124323 CreateComments: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:comments)
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.622279 #4] DEBUG -- :    (9.5ms)  CREATE TABLE "comments" ("id" bigserial primary key, "commentable_type" character varying,"commentable_id" integer, "user_id" integer, "body" text, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
   -> 0.0129s
== 20180708124323 CreateComments: migrated (0.0130s) ==========================

D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.624708 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Create (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20180708124323"]]
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.627539 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.5ms)  COMMIT
I, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.627685 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateVotes (20180709152735)
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.629887 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  BEGIN
== 20180709152735 CreateVotes: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:votes)
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.639342 #4] DEBUG -- :    (8.6ms)  CREATE TABLE "votes" ("id" bigserial primary key, "voteable_id" integer, "voteable_type" character varying, "user_id" character varying, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
   -> 0.0094s
== 20180709152735 CreateVotes: migrated (0.0095s) =============================

D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.642138 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Create (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20180709152735"]]
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.644622 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.1ms)  COMMIT
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.656312 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.671265 #4] DEBUG -- :    (5.5ms)  BEGIN
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.674884 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Create (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO "ar_internal_metadata" ("key", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "key"  [["key", "environment"], ["value", "production"], ["created_at", "2018-07-11 14:56:58.671911"], ["updated_at", "2018-07-11 14:56:58.671911"]]
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.677921 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.6ms)  COMMIT
D, [2018-07-11T14:56:58.680372 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.1ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(2612648823889037010)
➜  RubyOnCrack git:(master) ✗
```

Comment: Can you also write the line number for the given error if it's in the controller.

Comment: Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` before `heroku restart`? Heroku doesn't execute migrations automatically.

Comment: it doesn't give me an error when I run it on localhost..... that's also why I am a bit lost and don't know where to look exactly... When I run the Heroku logs it gives me: 2018-07-11T13:57:02.233498+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-11T13:57:02.233421 #4] FATAL -- : [978133b4-1604-436e-a9d9-7420d2dcb436] ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `user_id`):

Comment: Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` after initial deploy to migrate database?

Comment: yes I did. I also dropped the heroku and the local db and set it up new, but same same

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611604/heroku-rails-activerecordunknownattributeerror-unknown-attribute-user-id

Comment: ok I will try, thanks

Comment: please also see my edits

Comment: @Micromegas, are you sure that migrations files are identical locally and on heroku? Maybe some accidental change somewhere?

Comment: no they were different. please read my answer below, I could fix it with your help. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe the error is getting thrown here?

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(questions_params)
  @question.user = current_user
  if @question.save
    flash[:success] = "Fantastic #{@current_user.username} you posed a new question. Surely someone answers soon, stay tuned..."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
     render :new
  end
end
```

Out of curiosity, have you tried:

```
def create
  @question = current_user.questions.build(questions_params)
  if @question.save
    flash[:success] = "Fantastic #{@current_user.username} you posed a new question. Surely someone answers soon, stay tuned..."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
     render :new
  end
end
```

If that doesn't work, are you able to create a new record in console?

Comment: I tried this and it still gives me an error. But interestingly when I try with the console it gives me the following:  => #<Question id: nil, title: "test", description: "this is a description with more than 10 signs", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil>......  I don't quite understand why I can create a question on my app but not with the console???

Comment: to be more specific: 2.4.1 :001 > Question.create(title:"test", description:"this is a description with more than 10 signs")
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (3.1ms)  ROLLBACK
 => #<Question id: nil, title: "test", description: "this is a description with more than 10 signs", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil>
2.4.1 :002 >

Comment: You need to run `Question.create(title:"test", description:"this is a description with more than 10 signs", user: User.first)`. Question `belongs_to :user`, this association is validated by default

Comment: ahh of course, thank you!! ok with that command I can create questions just fine.... any more ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with your help. What I needed to do was:

1. completely delete and rebuild my local database
2. add again two migrations adding user to questions and answers, because the reset for some reason didn't do that
3. delete the Heroku app and deployed it again

Now it is working. Anyways, heress the link to the finished app in case you wanna check it out: https://rubyoncrack.herokuapp.com/

Comment: The app is so nice! :)

Comment: thank you so much! That will keep me smiling for a long time. thank you